# XPath in R doesn't work

Tags: r, xml, xpath

Pls, help me. I only start to work with xpath and try to use very simple example but it doesn't work. 
I get empty result of html.parse in the result. I expected to get "home" as a value.
Thanks for your help!

```
library('XML')
html.raw<-htmlTreeParse(
          'http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/index.html',
           useInternalNodes=T
           )
html.parse<-xpathApply(html.raw, ".//*[@id='breadcrumb']/p/a", xmlValue)
```

Comment: you xpath works in chrome

Comment: oh - i found mistake. I used wrong xpath w/o first dot: //*[@id='breadcrumb']/p/a righ

Comment: Use `rvest` & `xml2` so you can use the relative XPath: `pg <- rvest::read_html("http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/index.html") ;xml2::xml_find_all(pg, ".//*[@id='breadcrumb']/p/a")`